# How to test whether the activity has not been routed with Robolectric?

Tags: android, kotlin, robolectric

I have an activity which is as simple as this:

```
class HomeActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

        if (!this.userPreference.memberRegistered) {
            goToActivity(AuthActivity::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

So if the user is registered, it will stay at `HomeActivity`, otherwise it will route to `AuthActivity`.

`userPreference` is a wrapper around `SharedPreference`. Works well and well tested in another codebase.

I first tried whether `RuntimeEnvironment` from `Robolectric` could do the trick or not, and it works of course.

```
@Test
fun try_test() {
    val userPreference = UserPreference(
        Settings(SETTINGS_NAME, RuntimeEnvironment.application.applicationContext)
    )

    // default value should be false, PASS
    assertEquals(false, userPreference.memberRegistered)

    // change it to true, then it should be true, PASS
    userPreference.memberRegistered = true
    assertEquals(true, userPreference.memberRegistered)
}
```

Then I tried whether the route to `AuthActivity` works or not, and it works. The test pass.

```
@Test
fun should_go_to_AuthActivity_when_1st_start() {
    val homeActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(HomeActivity::class.java)
    val expectedIntent = Intent(homeActivity, AuthActivity::class.java)
    val actual = ShadowApplication.getInstance().nextStartedActivity
    assertEquals(expectedIntent.component, actual.component)
}
```

**Problem**

Then the problem is I don't know how to check if the activity stays at `HomeActivty` when `this.userPreference.memberRegistered = true`. The following test failed due to the reason that `actual is null`. It is because there is no routing happen, so `nextStartedActivity` is null, but how to verify that it stays at this activity from the test?

```
@Test
fun should_stay_at_HomeActivity_when_already_member() {
    val userPreference = UserPreference(
        Settings(SETTINGS_NAME, RuntimeEnvironment.application.applicationContext)
    )

    userPreference.memberRegistered = true

    val actual = ShadowApplication.getInstance().nextStartedActivity
    assertEquals(
        actual.component.shortClassName,
        ".ui.home.HomeActivity"
    )
}
```